Wrong font rendered, gets instantly fixed when I toggle Layout Inspector
I'm experiencing the weirdest issue with a custom font. It's rendered correctly everywhere in the app, with no problems.
I'm now introducing a PrimaryTabRow and the fonts are not rendered correctly in the Tab's titles.
However, as soon as I attach the Android Studio Layout Inspector to the device (or the emulator, same issue), then it instantly gets fixed on the fly.
If I launch with the Layout Inspector already attached and toggled, then the fonts still start wrong, but then are re-rendered correctly after a second or two.
If I switch to Dark Theme, the font is re-rendered correctly, and when I switch back to Light Theme is now also rendered correctly.
This is the only component in which this happens. At launch, the rest of the interface is already rendering the fonts correctly everywhere, from the start.
Here is the code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                val backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

                SideEffect {
                    window.statusBarColor = backgroundColor.toArgb()
                    window.statusBarColor = backgroundColor.toArgb()
                    window.navigationBarColor = backgroundColor.toArgb()

                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(
                        window,
                        window.decorView
                    ).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = useDarkIcons
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(
                        window,
                        window.decorView
                    ).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = useDarkIcons
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .systemBarsPadding()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                ) {
                    Scaffold(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(top = 24.dp),
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                title = {
                                    Text(
                                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium
                                    )
                                },
                                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    ) { innerPadding ->

                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(innerPadding)
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        ) {
                            var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

                            PrimaryTabRow(selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex, tabs = {
                                Tab(
                                    selected = selectedTabIndex == 0,
                                    onClick = {
                                        selectedTabIndex = 0
                                    },
                                    text = {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "Title Tab 1"
                                        )}
                                )
                                Tab(
                                    selected = selectedTabIndex == 1,
                                    onClick = {
                                        selectedTabIndex = 1
                                    },
                                    text = {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "Title Tab 2"
                                        )}
                                )
                            })

                            if (selectedTabIndex == 0) {
                                /* List composable, rendered correctly */
                            } else {
                                /* Different list composable, rendered correctly */
                            }

                            /* Carousel composable, rendered correctly */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Any clue what might be going on here?
-- EDIT --
As a temporary solution, I embedded the Font in my app, rather than using the downloadable approach with GoogleFont. This has solved it.
Still curious to understand why it happens exclusively in this component.
